# How do I add rownames to a flextable?

Tags: r

can't get add.rownames = TRUE to work in flextable

```
> tabelM
  Man Vrouw
  Gaat wel       337   442
  Goed              935  1150
  Slecht              57    83
  Zeer goed    262   243
  Zeer slecht    14    10

> rownames(tabelM)
[1] "Gaat wel"    "Goed"        "Slecht"      "Zeer goed"   "Zeer slecht"

> colnames(tabelM)
[1] "Man"   "Vrouw"


> flextable(tabelM)
#works fine


> flextable(tabelM,add.rownames = TRUE)
```

> Error in flextable(tabelM, add.rownames = TRUE) : 
>     unused argument (add.rownames = TRUE)

Comment: From `?flextable` this function doesn't have an argument called _add.rownames_.

Comment: Where did you get this argument name (`add.rownames`) from?

Answer (score 6):

You could use this workaround with the packages `tibble` and `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
flextable(tabelM %>% rownames_to_column("column name"))
```

As already mentioned in the comments, `flextable` has no argument called *add.rownames*

Comment: There is a FlexTable with capital letters including the add.rownames. https://davidgohel.github.io/ReporteRs/articles/FlexTable.html , see under "Usage".

Comment: @daan So are you using `FlexTable` (from {ReporteRs}) or `flextable` (from {flextable})?

Comment: Thanks, you solved the mystery. I found a workaround myself but it is not very handy because I would like to produce many tables, in different formats:tabel<-table(data$KLGGB201,data$geslacht)
tabelM<-as.data.frame.matrix(tabel)
tabelM$erv.gez<-rownames(tabelM)
tabelM<-tabelM[c(3,1,2)]
fl<-flextable(tabelM)

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @jkrainer works fine. Just a comment: like @Konrad mentioned, FlexTable is from "ReportRs" but as it says in here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ReporteRs/versions/0.8.10
That library will not evolve anymore and FlexTable objects are now implemented in package "flextable", which I think it has more limitations like not having the add.rownames argument.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to SO! If you have a comment rather than a full answer, you can use the comment function on either Questions or existing Answers.